# Problem with XeTeX input and output encoding

Tags: xetex, input-encodings, cjk, xecjk

As we all known, the TeX engine `XeTeX` takes UTF-8 as its default input and output encoding format. However, it provides two new primitive control sequences that could define input encoding:

- `\XeTeXinputencoding` defines the input encoding of the following text.
- `\XeTeXdefaultencoding` defines the input encoding of subsequent files to be read.

Thus, one could put one of these two commands to specify the encoding that will be read by XeTeX, which makes XeTeX can handle files that are encoded by other formats. But unfortunately, XeTeX provides no interface to specify the output encoding format, so that it would write files with UTF-8 in every situation, even if we put `\XeTeXinputencoding` or `\XeTeXdefaultencoding` at the beginning of the master `.tex` file.

A MWE that shows this problem:

```
\XeTeXdefaultencoding "GBK"
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{测试一}
这里是中文测试。
\clearpage
\section{测试二}
这里是中文测试。
\clearpage
\section{测试三}
这里是中文测试。
\clearpage
\section{测试四}
这里是中文测试。
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

(Note that there is no selection of CJK fonts here.)

If you save this piece of code as `GBK` (M$ calls it `cp936`), and compile it by `XeLaTeX`, no error will be reported. However, you would not be surprised that the `.toc` and `.aux` files are written as `UTF-8`.

The fact interpreted above will lead to another embarrassing tangible. These temp files were written by `UTF-8`, whereas the master file was saved as `GBK`. Hence, if we put `\XeTeXinputencoding "GBK"` at the begining of the master file, temp files will be read as `UTF-8`; if we use `\XeTeXdefaultencoding "GBK"`, then temp fils will be read as `GBK` (but they themselves are `UTF-8`).

ERROR occurred so quietly but sadly.

Is there any clues or hints?

Comment: Isn't using UTF-8 alone better?

Comment: @egreg Yes indeed. But there are many old Chinese `.tex` documents were saved in `GBK` (China mainland, `Big5` in Taiwan) using `pdfLaTeX` + `CJK`. We hope that we could find a comfort way to help these documents to migrate smoothly to `XeLaTeX` with `xeCJK`.

Comment: @egreg What's more, these users are not able to understand the difference between these two encoding formats. Forcing them changing the encoding is not a easy-achieving scheme.

Comment: `iconv -f GBK -t UTF-8 filename.tex > filenameUTF8.tex` is the best procedure, I believe. There are also GUI converters.

Comment: @egreg You know, the package/documentclass `ctex` provides an easy way to generate CJK document with LaTeX. One can use `\documentclass{ctexart}` to produce a Chinese document. Since `GBK` is widely used in China mainland, we hope that there will be an easy way to combine `GBK` and `XeTeX` together.

Comment: 我不认为这个功能太值得做，旧文档没必要迁移，没必要用 XeTeX。新文档更不需要迁移这个功能，说服吴凌云打包时保持新版本 WinEdt 用 UTF-8 编码而不是 GBK 编码会更有意义。

Comment: @Ch'enMeng: Old document maintainers will not take it. It is useless to make old documents (via `ctex` package) compilable under XeTeX. And I myself do not hope so either.

Comment: @LeoLiu 不过我看 2.9.2 的记录里，他还专门发布了一次更新用来调整 WinEdt 的默认编码。不知道他怎么考虑的。

Comment: @LeoLiu I was just wondering that is there any chance to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't convert to utf8 (which is naturally the best as it will make life much easier) imho the best is to add  `\XeTeXinputencoding "GBK"` at the begin of every file (master + input files) which uses this encoding.

`\XeTeXdefaultencoding` is simply misnamed: it can't be used to declare the default encoding of a complete project. (But you can use it to declare the encoding of a bundle of files - if you are sure that auxiliary files don't interfere).

Comment: `UTF-8` was designed to make life much easier and better, however, there is an precondition, that everyone do use this encoding format. Tens of millions of old `.tex` documents were written and saved as `GBK`, and thus the precondition does not hold. Hence, finding a way to help these user (have old `.tex` documents saved as `GBK`) moving from `(pdf)LaTeX` + `CJK` to `XeLaTeX` + `xeCJK` really needs to be addressed.

Comment: I can't agree more with Ulrike Fischer. All new documents using XeTeX/LuaTeX should always use UTF-8 encoding. For the old documents, let it be.

Comment: @LeoLiu Agree with the new documents' part.